# Member Directory Module in dotnetnuke 6.2

Tags: active-directory, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

how to display members in member directory module in dotnetnuke according to individual Group.i am able to set group filter for only single group not for multiple...can anyone suggest how to set it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the member directory to work for a specific group, you would need to place the module onto a Group configured page. If you use Social Groups in DNN, there is an auto-setup option that will create the pages for groups, which should include member directory. Check out the

Getting started with DotNetNuke 6.2 Series

tutorials on this page http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training/Tutorials.aspx

Comment: Hi Chris,we have used member directory module and social group module....we have 5-6 groups on 1 page....right now   when we click on any group its redirect to group activity page ,here we add console module,on console module when we click on member ,there should be member of that individual group on member page..?but right now we are not able to differentiate individual groups through filteration....  because we have to use only single member directory module...if we set  filter for one group,then all groups shows same members...

Comment: I've got this setup on http://www.sccaforums.com/community/group-activity/groupid/8 and it works fine, if you click on Members, it shows you only the list of Members for a group

Comment: Thanks Chris.....can we get the settings ..how they filter by group  for individual group???

Comment: The filter happens based on the GroupId being passed in the URL (ex: http://www.sccaforums.com/community/group-activity/members/groupid/8)

Comment: thats fine Chris.....but how we can set filter by group in single module for multiple groups..........we can set only for single group......is they done through coding??

Comment: I don't believe you can have a member directory module show you members for MULTIPLE but not all groups. Not without code

Comment: we have only single module on member page .....when we click on radiobutton of Group by filter in module setting ,there is 1 dropdown that shows all group,from there we can set only one group.....can you tell me if i have 5 groups and i added 5 member module then may we i can set filter of every group one by one......but there is one problem,how i can hide all other member directory module,when i click on particular group......thanks Chris

Comment: At this point I am not really sure what you are asking anymore.

Comment: just want to know is this possible throgh coding or setting?

Comment: I would have to assume, that the code, is looking for a setting, which likely stores a single groupid, and loads based on that setting, or it loads based on a querystring parameter. Extending it to take multiple IDs instead of just a single, would likely require code changes in DNN.